# Implementing async/await pattern for manually generated WCF (client-side) proxies

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

Given this interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IProductService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Product Get(int id);
}
```

I would like to **manually** (that is, without using scvutil or Add Service Reference in VS) create a client-side proxy.

I do it in the following way

```
public class ProductService: IProductService
{
    readonly ChannelFactory<IProductService> factory;

    public ProductService()
    {
        factory = new ChannelFactory<IProductService>("*");
    }

    public Product Get(int id)
    {
        var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
        return channel.Get(id);
    }
}
```

**My problem is** that I also want async/await version of this method, only on client-side, server side is still synchronous.

I want this to be a **generic solution** because I have many methods and services of this sort.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use _async all the way_ starting _at the server_ rather than using the inevitable `Task.Run()` or `FromResult()`?

Comment: It would of course, the only reason not to is high cost :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using `ChannelFactory` to allow for async-await your interface needs to return a `Task` or `Task<T>`.

It will force your server side to also return a task but you can do that synchronously with `Task.CompletedTask` and `Task.FromResult` if you insist on keeping it synchronous (though why would you if you have the option).

For example:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IProductService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<Product> GetAsync(int id);
}

class ProductService : IProductService
{
    ChannelFactory<IProductService> factory;

    public ProductService()
    {
        factory = new ChannelFactory<IProductService>("*");
    }

    public Task<Product> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
        return channel.GetAsync(id);
    }
}

class ProductAPI : IProductService
{
    public Task<Product> GetAsync(int id) => Task.FromResult(Get(id))
}
```

Comment: And when calling the operation from the client side would immediately free the calling thread and reclaim it when the task finishes? (that is, is it "truly" async?)

Comment: @Elad yes. `ChannelFactory` supports async natively. It doesn't create a fake `Task` over a blocking operation.

Comment: Which of those two classes is intended to be the client?

Comment: @StingyJack "Which of those two classes is intended to be the client?" ProductService is the service, ProductAPI is the client.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually do that without changing the service itself. You can simply define a second interface which contains async and `Task` returning versions of the methods and is marked with `[ServiceContract(Name = "NameOfTheIterfaceWhichIsActuallyExposedOnTheServer")]`

In the example you mentioned you would define a second interface with `GetAsync()` operation:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "IProductService")]
public interface IProductServiceAsync
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<Product> GetAsync(int id);
}
```

and even though your service still implements and exposes `IProductService` you can use `ChannelFactory<IProductServiceAsync>` to call into it. As long as the method names match the `GetFoo`/`GetFooAsync` pattern everything will *just work*. That's how **Add Service Reference** in Visual Studio can generate you an async service reference to a synchronous service.

See [Calling a synchronous WCF method asynchronously using ChannelFactory](https://marcinjuraszek.com/2018/01/async-wcf-with-channelfactory.html) for a more detailed explanation on how this work.

Comment: What if my service has hundreds of methods? Is there an automatic and programmatic way to do so?